# Travis build fails: Ruby ruby-2.2.5 is not installed

Tags: ruby, travis-ci

My travis build suddenly started to fail with (between *before_deploy* and *deploy*):

```
Ruby ruby-2.2.5 is not installed.

The command "rvm 2.2.5 --fuzzy do ruby -S gem install dpl" failed and exited with 2 during .
```

Ideas how to fix this?

.travis.yaml

```
before_deploy:
- export PATH=$PATH:${CLOUD_SDK_PATH}/bin
- openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_c09a72752447_key -iv $encrypted_c09a72752447_iv -in contrib/gae/secrets.tar.enc -out secrets.tar -d
- tar xvf secrets.tar

deploy:

  - provider: script
    skip_cleanup: true
    script: fab deploy:target='DEV',ci=True
    on: develop
```

Comment: Same issue here. Probably an issue with Travis

Comment: I think [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6789) might be the same issue, it was created 4 days ago

Comment: It mentions another Ruby version though

Comment: Travis seems to have fixed it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just hit this too. As a workaround, you might be able to install ruby 2.2.5 explicitly, adding an install command to my `before_install` step works for me:

```
before_install:
  - rvm install 2.2.5
```

Comment: It took 177.37s to install

Comment: We're hearing that travis have got a fix underway - hopefully this won't be necessary for long!

Comment: I don't want to install ruby, to fix travis bugs ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, everyone. We had a bad deploy earlier today. This should be fixed now.